# Making a executable into a shell command using a C program

Tags: c, shell, executable

I've a executable named say "sortx". Now I want to write a C program which transforms this executable into a shell command.

ex:
./sortx numbers.txt

After running the C program on "sortx" what I want is :

sortx numbers.txt

Comment: Why do you need a C program?  Would `mv sortx /usr/bin/sortx` be what you are looking for?

Comment: In your opinion what is a difference between a shell program and a console C application ?

Comment: make a symbolic link to your executable and put that link in `/usr/bin` (ask root for permission): `ln -s /home/user673919/project/sortx/sortx /usr/bin/sortx`.

Comment: Here's the entire thing : I've a program sort.c..
now, 

cc sort.c -o sortx Now, sortx is executable and I have to run by typing ..

./sortx numbers.txt

But I want to chage sortx or do something using a C program only so that I might be able to do this ..

sortx numbers.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the directory in which *sortx* is present to $PATH. This way you could execute your program locally, like,

*sortx numbers.txt*

To add directory ~/my_bin to the beginning of the $PATH environment variable, add or update this in your **.bash_profile**:

```
PATH=~/my_bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

On Linux to make any script or program globally executable (e.g "sortx" rather than "./sortx") you can put the script in wither /usr/bin or /bin -- I prefer /usr/bin :)

Answer (score 1):

- [I/O Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)
- [Advanced Shell Topics: stdin, stdout and redirection](http://suso.suso.org/docs/adv_shell/ioredirect.phtml)